# How to play a video on mobile browser that doesnot have html5 and flash support?

Tags: html, video, jwplayer, video.js, video-player

I am just wondering, How to play a video on mobile browser that does not have html5 and flash support (I don't want end user to download my video ) ?

I am ready to use open source or paid players . Please suggest your inputs.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What browser are you trying to support here?

Answer (score 1):

Use QuickTime for example. For Firefox see its description here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/quicktime-plugin-play-audio-and-video

But I would prefer to use HTML5, as it is supported by all browsers for now.